# Selenium won't recognise elements when the page chages

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I just started learning python and wanted to experiment with a loop.
So this code is meant to go on the link, look for the ID: next and click on if there is none the script will print "Done". On the first page the script works fine, on the second page the script won't recognize the element, and so he prints done.

Here it is (Everything needed for the code to run is already imported)

```
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
loop = 10

##Navigating to the website
driver.get("https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/mississauga-peel-region/page-/c37l1700276?ad=offering&price=__1780")

while loop > 0 :
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        next = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Next']"))
        )
        next.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        loop = loop - 1
    except:
        time.sleep(7.5)
        loop = loop - 100
        print('Done')
```

Comment: next.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) just use .click()